# CircleCI Trouble with gradlew in another folder

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, circleci

I have a problem with CircleCI that I can not get to work because my gradlew file is not in the root of my repository. As my depot is deprived here is a summary of his architectures:

```
root
-----> app_folder
------------> some folders
------------> some files
------------> gradlew
------> some files and folders
------> circle.yml
```

I tried to go into the app_folder folder using the cd command and change the path variable but nothing of it worked

**circle.yml**

```
#
# Build configuration for Circle CI
#

machine:
    environment:
        PATH: "~/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME/app_folder:$PATH"
        ANDROID_HOME: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
        GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'
        _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
        ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT: "10"
        ANDROID_API_LEVEL: 25
        ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION: 25.0.2
    java:
        version: oraclejdk7

dependencies:
    cache_directories:
        - ~/.gradle
        - ~/.android
        - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras

    pre:
        - if [ ! -d "$ANDROID_HOME/tools" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "tools"; fi
        - if [ ! -d "$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "android-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL"; fi
        - if [ ! -d "$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION"; fi
        - if [ ! -d "$ANDROID_HOME/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "addon-google_apis-google-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL"; fi
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-google-m2repository"
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-google-google_play_services"
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"

test:
  override:
    # start the emulator
    - emulator -avd circleci-android24 -no-audio -no-window:
        background: true
        parallel: true
    # wait for it to have booted
    - circle-android wait-for-boot
    # unlock the emulator screen
    - sleep 30
    - adb shell input keyevent 82
    # run tests  against the emulator.
    - echo $PATH
    - cd app_folder && .\gradlew connectedAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex
- .\\app_folder\\gradlew connectedAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex
- .\app_folder\\gradlew connectedAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex
- .\gradlew connectedAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex ~/github_name/app_folder
    # copy the build outputs to artifacts
    - cp -r app_folder/app/build/outputs $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS
    # copy the test results to the test results directory.
    - cp -r app_folder/app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/* $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two options here. The quickest is to specify a [custom build directory](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/#build-dir). Using your example, this would be:

```
general:
  build_dir: app_folder
```

This is because per CircleCI Docs:

> CircleCI will run its inference as well as all build commands from
>   that directory.

The second option would be to not rely on CircleCI's Inference commands at all and instead run everything, like Gradle yourself. You're already overriding the `test` phase, so you'd need to override the `dependencies` phase as well and run `gradle dependencies` yourself.

For example:

```
dependencies:
  override:
    - gradle --project-dir app_folder dependencies
```

-Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add this on the top :

```
general:
  build_dir: your_folder
```